# jQuery Animate Individual Elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a few elements independently. As a start I have tried one such element whose class & id i have defined as "star". When the element moves 800 px from its original position I want it to stop. And I have correctly done that. But the issue is bringing it back to its original position. I want it to start going back once the element is visible on the screen. Currently it stops at 800px. If I keep on scrolling to further right it stays there at 800px. But when i start scrolling left it starts moving left immediately. So i can't see the desired effect. And please also tell me if there is a better way of doing the same thing. Because the way I am doing it, I am afraid it is going to get very complicated when I try to animate more elements

```
$(function() {
var lastmove = 0;
$("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    var move = 0;
    var move1 = 0;
    if (lastmove == 0 && delta == 1) { 
        //do nothing 
    }
    else {
        move = (lastmove * delta * -1) + 30;
    }
    if ((lastmove-move) > 30) { move = move * -1; }
    if (move > 800) { 
        move = 800; 
    }
    var position = $("#star").position();
    if (position.left < 0) { move = 0; }
    if (position.left > 800) { move = 800; }
    lastmove = move;
    $(".star").stop().animate({left: move}, "slow");
    event.preventDefault();
            });
         });
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Wjf/)

Comment: please provide sample code here in question. First it is unreasonable for others to have to go to your site and look through source, and second the link provided may be changed at some time making this question useless to others in the future. A demo in jsfiddle.net is really helpful

Comment: Noted! And changes made accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/MZUhh/1/

```
  if(this.scrollLeft > 800 && delta == 1) return false;
```

Simplified Code:

```
$(function () {
$("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
  this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
  if (this.scrollLeft > 800) return false;
  $(".star").stop().animate({left: this.scrollLeft}, "slow");
  event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MZUhh/2/)

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly! But the animation on the way back isn't smooth. It doesn't reach the start point by the time the scroll bar reaches at point 0. Any suggestions? And is there an easier way to do animations like these?

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly. Now the code size has also decreased drastically. Hopefully will be able to animate other elements similarly. Thank you once again.

Comment: Welcome.. Happy to be Helpful... :)